# How to fix up this problem with screen bash command?

Tags: bash, gnu-screen

I accidently deleted `/var/run/screen/S-root/25771.pts-0` and when I try to run screen again

```
screen bash ...
```

it reports:

`/var/run/screen/S-root/25771.pts-0: No such file or directory`

How can I recover it?

Comment: Is this a superuser.com question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means you are already in screen named "bash"

Just exit it with "exit" command. And run again "screen bash"

Answer (score 20):

Check to see if you have the environment variable `STY` set:

```
[user@machine ~] echo $STY
25771.pts-0
```

If the variable is set, then you are telling `screen` to reattach to an existing session. If that session doesn't exist, then you will see the error you are getting.

To solve this, just clear the environment variable by running:

```
export STY=
```

and try starting `screen` again.

This scenario may have occurred because you previously had a screen session running (which setup the STY environment variable for you) which has now closed. For example:

```
xterm
screen
# The following xterm will inherit the existing STY environment variable.
xterm &
# close the initial xterm, and in the new xterm run the following:
screen
```

The final call to `screen` will give you your error, because it still has the environment variable `STY` from the original (now-gone) `screen` session.

Comment: Or just do `unset STY`.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO if you deleted the screen socket, there is no method to recover that screen instance.

You have to exit from screen and run it again.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't find a session to exit or kill and get the same "No such file or directory" error every time you try to start screen, try "screen -wipe".